# Trigger.io web is failing on Ubuntu 12.04 with - "Failed when running npm: npm WARN package.json forge-web@0.0.1 No description"

Tags: trigger.io

I'm getting a error when trying to run the web version. (everything works fine one the phone).

Here is the error I get from the console.

```
[INFO] JavaScript check complete
[INFO] Verifying your configuration settings...
[INFO] Configuration settings check complete
[INFO] Development build created. Use forge run to run your app.
[INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.71
[ERROR] Failed when running npm: npm WARN package.json forge-web@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN package.json forge-web@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json forge-web@0.0.1 No README data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm WARN engine express@3.4.6: wanted: {"node":">= 0.8.0"} (current: {"node":"v0.6.12","npm":"1.3.12"})
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.11.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/1.3.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/1.3.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.11.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm WARN engine connect@2.11.2: wanted: {"node":">= 0.8.0"} (current: {"node":"v0.6.12","npm":"1.3.12"})
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/1.1.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/multiparty/2.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/-/negotiator-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/1.1.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/-/raw-body-1.1.2.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/multiparty/2.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/multiparty/-/multiparty-2.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-0.6.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/-/negotiator-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/-/raw-body-1.1.2.tgz
npm ERR! addPlacedTarball Could not remove "/home/eugene/.npm/negotiator/0.3.0/package"
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/home/eugene/Vouch/trigger/development/web/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect'
npm ERR! error rolling back  connect@2.11.2 { [Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/home/eugene/Vouch/trigger/development/web/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -1,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/home/eugene/Vouch/trigger/development/web/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect' }
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/home/eugene/Vouch/trigger/development/web/node_modules/express'
npm ERR! error rolling back  express@3.4.6 { [Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/home/eugene/Vouch/trigger/development/web/node_modules/express']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -1,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/home/eugene/Vouch/trigger/development/web/node_modules/express' }
npm ERR! Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/home/eugene/.npm/negotiator/0.3.0/package'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-41-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/eugene/Vouch/trigger/development/web
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.12
npm ERR! path /home/eugene/.npm/negotiator/0.3.0/package
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -1
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-0.6.5.tgz
npm ERR! addPlacedTarball Could not remove "/home/eugene/.npm/qs/0.6.5/package"
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/multiparty/-/multiparty-2.2.0.tgz
npm ERR! addPlacedTarball Could not remove "/home/eugene/.npm/multiparty/2.2.0/package"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/eugene/Vouch/trigger/development/web/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code undefined
npm ERR! not ok code -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the version of express used in Trigger Web apps needs a newer version of node (at least 0.8) than the version in the official Ubuntu LTS repositories (0.6).

You can install node 0.10 from a PPA, which should solve your problem: https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/